# How to start a session from a PHP script that returns a JSON result to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a loginscript that starts a session containing either admin or any possible other user.

Everything in my script is returned as JSON (messages and what user logged in). But in that same script I also start a session according to what user logged in.

After I get a result I go to a page depending what user logged in, but the session can't be found there. I try to echo its contents but it shows nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

My php script:

```
session_start();
$conn = new Connection;
$username = $_POST['username'];
$userpassword = $_POST['userpassword'];

if(empty($username) && empty($userpassword)){
    $logindata = array(
        'userdata' => '',
        'message' => 'Vul een gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord in',
    );
    echo json_encode($logindata);
}else if(empty($username)){
    $logindata = array(
        'userdata' => '',
        'message' => 'Vul een gebruikersnaam in',
    );
    echo json_encode($logindata);
}else if(empty($userpassword)){
    $logindata = array(
        'userdata' => '',
        'message' => 'Vul een wachtwoord in',
    );
}else{
  //Both filled in, begin logincode:
  $getuser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$conn->real_escape_string($username)."'";
  $getusercon = $conn->query($getuser);
  $getuser = $getusercon->fetch_assoc();

  if($userpassword == $getuser['password']){
    if($getuser['rights'] == '1'){
      $_SESSION['user'] = 'admin';
      $loginresult = array(
        'login_result' => 'success',
     );
      $logindata = array(
        'userdata' => $_SESSION['user'],
     );
    echo json_encode($logindata);
    }else{
      $_SESSION['user'] = $getuser['username'];
      $loginresult = array(
        'login_result' => 'success',
     );
      $logindata = array(
        'userdata' => $_SESSION['user'],
     );
    echo json_encode($logindata);
    }
  }else{
        $logindata = array(
            'userdata' => '',
            'message' => 'Wachtwoord en gebruikersnaam komen niet overeen',
     );
    echo json_encode($logindata);
  }
}
```

My AJAX code:

```
// Login Ajax Code
$( "#content" ).on("submit", "#loginform", function( event ) {
  // Stop normal form behaviour
  event.preventDefault();
  // Retrieve input fields and their values
  var $form = $( this ),
  $username = $form.find( "input[name='username']" ).val(),
  $userpassword = $form.find( "input[name='userpassword']" ).val(),
  url = $form.attr( "action" );
  // Post above values to the action of the form
  var posting = $.post( url, { username: $username, userpassword: $userpassword} );
  // Show result in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    if(obj.userdata == ''){
      $( "#loginresult" ).empty().slideDown('fast').append( obj.message );
    }else if(obj.userdata == 'admin'){
      window.location.href = "http://www.website.nl/addcompany.php";
      console.log('dit is een admin');
    }else if(obj.userdata == 'user'){
      window.location.href = "http://www.website.nl/index2.php";
      console.log('dit is een user');
    }
  }, "json");
});
```

In the header that is both on `addcompany.php` and `index2.php` I try this:

```
<?PHP echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>test
```

It shows test but not the session contents.

Comment: Are you using it from a cross domain - your API calls are in different domain in contrast to that you are requesting from?

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: I dont see anywhere in this PHP code where you start the session? i.e. no `start_session()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I forgot to add it, it's there. In my connection.php and at the top of my login script.

Comment: @PraveenKumar No it's all on the same domain

Comment: @twan Weird then... Session data will be carried in that case. Have you checked with other browsers? Is your current browser has its cookies disabled?